# Find unique values across two very large lists in most memory efficient way

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set, unique

I have a very large list of lists (containing 13 lists of ~41 million entries each, i.e. ~500 million entries in total, each one a short string). I need to take that list and find the union of two of the sublists, i.e. find all unique elements across them and save them into a new list in the most memory efficient way. Ordering is not essential. One way would be:

```
c = a[1] + a[2]
c = set(c)
```

But is that the most memory efficient way? An added complication is the fact that some of the entries in `a[1]` or `a[2]` may contain more than one element (i.e. look something like `a[1]=[['val1'],['val2','val3'],...]`). How would I best deal with that so that `val2` and `val3` show up as separate entries in the final results?

Comment: what you mean by *compare two of the sublists*? can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?

Comment: How do you want to handle stuff like `['val2','val3']`? Should that be added as a single item to the final list, or do you want to add `'val2'` & `'val3'` as separate items?

Comment: As seprate items. I will edit the question. Thanks for the question.

Comment: 1). To minimize RAM usage, is it acceptable to you to delete sublists once they are processed? 2). Would you consider a solution that involves writing your data to disk so you can read it back in small RAM-friendly chunks?

Comment: Writing the data to disc and reading it back could be an option. I will still need the initial list unaltered unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be 100% sure that doing this is the most memory efficent way to do it but it I'd find it simplest:

```
l3 = set(l1)
l3.update(l2)
l3 = list(l3)
```

this should not allocate more memory than necessary:

```
l3  = []
for i in l1:
  if i not in l3:
    l3.append(i)
for i in l2:
  if i not in l3:
    l3.append(i)
```

Comment: It's a O(N²) solution. It will take about 3 months for the whole problem.

Comment: if we were talking time complexity the first solution ought to be nice.
with x% overlap it took y seconds to get l3 as a list on my laptop:
0% overlap 2.9s,
50% overlap 2.9s,
100% overlap 2.5s

Comment: You must use set, because `x in set` is O(1) , and `x in list` is O(N). Have you try with len(l) = 41 000 000 ?

Comment: Yes the numbers I supplied was running the first solution with l1 & l2 with 41 000 000 entries respectively containging integers (long strings would slow it down). I only supplied the other one since it does use less memory which was the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are most efficient than numpy here for short strings. with these data:

```
import random
N=13 #13
M=100000
ll=[["".join([l for l in [ 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[randint(0,25)]\
for k in range(4)]]) for l in range(M)] for h in range(N)] #example data
```

just do :

```
sets= [set(l) for l in ll]
res = [[list(sets[i]|sets[j]) for j in range(i+1,N)] for i in range(N)]
```

it will take a few minutes for the result for M=41 000 000 , if no problem of memory size.

Comment: This is another approach that I came across after some searching:
`merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([a[1],a[2]))
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(merged))
unique = list(set(merged))`
Would your solution be faster?

Comment: do you want union or intersection ? this solution give union. But think itertools does'nt affect performance here.

Comment: Could you explain what `sets= [set(l) for l in ll]
res = [[list(sets[i]|sets[j]) for j in range(i+1,N)] for i in range(N)]` does? I am struggling a bit to follow the notation I fear.